# django - deleting User raises integrity error

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

I am doing a "Reddit Clone" using django and these are my models:

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    owner = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dob = models.DateField()
    karma = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Subreddit(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True, related_name='subreddits')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    subscribers = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, blank=True, related_name='subscriptions')
    moderators = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, blank=True, related_name='moderates')

class Post(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    votes = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    subreddit = models.ForeignKey(Subreddit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Comment(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    votes = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    parent_post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parent_comment = models.ForeignKey("Comment", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now, I tried to delete a `user` who just made 1 `comment`. When I tried to delete the `user` from `django admin`, I got the following error.

> IntegrityError at /admin/auth/user/2/delete/ (1451, 'Cannot delete or
>   update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`redditdb`.`redditapp_comment`, CONSTRAINT
>   `redditapp_comment_owner_id_fdc65fee_fk_redditapp_profile_id` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`owner_id`) REFERENCES `redditapp_profile` (`id`))')

I did user `on_delete=models.CASCADE` so I don't know why I am getting this error. Do I need to restructure the foreign keys in my models?

---

Actually reddit follows a structure where when a parent comment is deleted, its child comments won't get deleted. The deleted parent comment will be dashed or striked out and its child comments are still shown. Knowing this, how do I move forward with my code, should I delete profiles at all?

Comment: `DO_NOTHING` take no action. this causes an `IntegrityError`, you can try set `on_delete` ettribute of `ForeignKey` to `on_delete=models.CASCADE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Comment is not directly related to User. It is related through Profile. SO when you delete User, its Profile is deleted. which affects the comment, as it becomes dangling.

You can either have

```
owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

or

```
owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING ,null=True)
```

Comment: What approach would be better for the update that I made in the post?

Comment: I think you should use owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING ,null=True) while rendering the comments if it has a user show its name or else show anonymous user

Comment: I agree. But that means that we are storing data which is deleted and no longer required. Is there no other way?

Comment: What data is no longer required ?

Comment: A user deletes his profile, now all that user's data is "no longer required".

Comment: yes and we are deleting users data but since we want "reddit like modeling" users comments are required hence we are not deleting it.

Comment: I think the second or option referring is `owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)`

Answer (score 0):

The error mention that the `owner_id` of the app's `redditapp` `Comment` model references 
the `id` of the app's `redditapp` `Profile` model, and the `Comment` model `owner` ForeignKey on_delete attribute
is set to [models.DO_NOTHIN](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DO_NOTHING)

> **DO_NOTHING:**
>
> Take no action. If your database backend enforces
>   referential integrity,  this will cause an **IntegrityError** unless you
>   manually add an SQL ON DELETE constraint to the database field.

Your best choice is `on_delete=models.CASCADE` because comments are associated with a specific `Profile`, if the `Profile` is deleted its `Comment`s become anonymous with no identifying `Profile`.

**Edit:**

Here if the parent comment is deleted the child will not, and the reference to the parent comment will be set to **null**

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    votes = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    parent_post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parent_comment = models.ForeignKey("Comment", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

The same goes for `Post` model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    votes = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    subreddit = models.ForeignKey(Subreddit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Or you can **prevent the deletion** of the profile all along using [models.PROTECT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.PROTECT)

Comment: How will u tackle the problem that I mentioned at the end of the question?

Comment: Making parent_comment null doesn't help as I won't be able to structure comments in front end. In front end, the deleted comment should be striked out and its comments should go intended under it. So, making parent_comment null, I won't know where to put this comment.

Answer (score -1):

You have two options:

```
parent_post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

or

```
parent_post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING )
```